# std::copy for dynamically allocated pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, copy

This is probably a very newbie question. The class I'm working on (let's call it MyClass) contains the following variables

```
 int nbins;
 double * bins; // = new double[nbins+i]
```

Since I'm implementing a copy constructor

```
 MyClass( const MyClass& source )
```

I need to copy `source.bins`. I was going to use `std::copy` from `algorithm`, but all the examples I've found show how to copy static array like `double bins[] = ...` or standard data structure like `std::vector`. I can't find any example in which `std::copy` is used on pointers like `double * bins = new double[nbins+i]`. So, my question is: is legal to use `std::copy` on pointers, like for example

```
double * bins = new double[nbins+1]; //is this necessary?
std::copy( std::begin( source.bins ), std::end(source.bins), std::begin(bins) );
```

or should I rather rely on the C `memcpy`

```
double * bins = new double[nbins+1]; //again, is this necessary?
memcpy( source.bins, bins, (nbins+1) /* *sizeof(double) ?*/ );
```

So, my questions are basically two:

1) Does `std::end(bins)` know where is the end of `bins (=new double[nbins+1])`?

2) Do I need to allocate the memory for the destination before doing the copy? Or the `copy` (or `memcpy`) takes care of that?

Comment: You may want to use `std::vector<double>` instead.

Comment: I wish I could use vectors :) but the framework I'm working in doesn't accept vectors. Yes, I could use vector::data() mumble mumble...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> 1) Does `std::end(bins)` know where is the end of `bins (=new double[nbins+1])`?

No, `std::begin` and `std::end` require that the array be of fixed size.

> 2) Do I need to allocate the memory for the destination before doing the copy? Or the copy (or memcpy) takes care of that?

You need to allocate the memory. Both `copy` and `memcpy` assume that you provide them with a block of memory that can be written to.

So yes, you can use `std::copy`, but without `std::begin` and `std::end`:

```
double * bins = new double[nbins+1]; //is this necessary?
std::copy( source.bins , source.bins + N, bins );
```

where `N` is the length or the array pointed at by `source.bins`. Obviously you have to make sure you are not accessing either array out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks, that was the most important of  my doubts. Now, the destination needs to be allocated beforehand? What happen if it's allocated but with wrong size? edit: both questions have been answered. thanks!

Comment: @Blackphoenix I expanded my answer. If the allocated size is too small, you will get undefined behaviour. If it is too large, it won't matter, except that you are not fully using the allocated memory.